# PHP IF/ELSE condition not working as expected

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to implement multiple if else conditions which check the status of a proposal and should only execute a specific code if the status code is set to 1 or 5.

For some reason I'm having difficulties with implementing this. Currently the logic in the code is if the proposal status does not match 1 or 5 then returns a message otherwise execute the next query. When I specify just the one number i.e. (1 or 5) it will work fine.

Another problem I am facing with if and else conditions is in this part:

```
if ($count == 1) {

        $feedback = '<p class="text-danger"> You have already accepted an application. You cannot accept or apply for any others. If this is a mistake then please contact the supervisor concerned directly.</p>'; 
    }

    if ($count < 1) {

        $status = $db_conx->prepare ("SELECT status_code FROM record WHERE student_record_id = :user_record_id AND proposal_id = :proposal");

        $status->bindParam(':user_record_id', $user_record_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $status->bindParam(':proposal', $proposal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $status->execute();

        $proposalstatus = $status->fetchColumn();

        if($proposalstatus != 1)
        {
                //echo $proposalstatus;
            $feedback = '<p class="text-danger">The proposal is not at a status where it can be accepted</p>';
        }
    }

    else {
```

This works when I run each part separately but when I try and put it together in an if statement it fails and doesn't check for these conditions at all and just completes the task which updates the database and displays a success message.

The full code is here:

```
try
    {
     $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

     $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     $username = $_SESSION['username'];

     $sql = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT username, user_record_id FROM login_details
        WHERE username = :username");

     $sql->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

     $sql->execute();
     $user_record_id = $sql->fetchColumn(1);

     $proposal = $_POST['proposal_id'];

     $acceptCheck = $db_conx->prepare ("SELECT * FROM record WHERE student_record_id = :user_record_id AND status_code = 3");
     $acceptCheck->bindParam(':user_record_id', $user_record_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $acceptCheck->execute();

     $count = $acceptCheck->rowCount();

     if ($count == 1) {

        $feedback = '<p class="text-danger"> You have already accepted an application. You cannot accept or apply for any others. If this is a mistake then please contact the supervisor concerned directly.</p>'; 
    }

    if ($count < 1) {

        $status = $db_conx->prepare ("SELECT status_code FROM record WHERE student_record_id = :user_record_id AND proposal_id = :proposal");

        $status->bindParam(':user_record_id', $user_record_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $status->bindParam(':proposal', $proposal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $status->execute();

        $proposalstatus = $status->fetchColumn();

        if($proposalstatus != 1 || 5) //status must be either 'Approved' code 1 or 'Held' code 5
        {
                //echo $proposalstatus;
            $feedback = '<p class="text-danger">The proposal is not at a status where it can be accepted</p>';
        }
    }

    else {

                //Update all application records to 'Not available' when a proposal has been accepted

        $updateOtherRecords = $db_conx->prepare("UPDATE record SET status_code = 8, last_updated = now()
            WHERE proposal_id = :proposal");
        $updateOtherRecords->bindParam(':proposal', $proposal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $updateOtherRecords->execute();

                //Update other applicationa for the user concerned to 'Rejected'

        $updateUserRecord = $db_conx->prepare("UPDATE record SET status_code = 7, last_updated = now()
            WHERE student_record_id = :user_record_id");
        $updateUserRecord->bindParam(':user_record_id', $user_record_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $updateUserRecord->execute();

                //Update the proposal concerned and assign it to the user

        $update = $db_conx->prepare("UPDATE record SET status_code = 3, last_updated = now()
            WHERE proposal_id = :proposal AND student_record_id = :user_record_id");
        $update->bindParam(':user_record_id', $user_record_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $update->bindParam(':proposal', $proposal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $update->execute();

        $feedback = '<p class="text-success"> The proposal has been successfully accepted <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"/></p>';
    }
}
```

I really need to know how I can sort this because I'll be using if and else a lot in this statement. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The expression `$proposalstatus != 1 || 5` doesn't do what you mean it to. You have to fully express both conditions so it looks like  `if($proposalstatus != 1 && $proposalstatus != 5)` which means changing it to `&&` to make the logic work.

Comment: `vardump($proposalstatus);` , you should use.

Comment: print_r($proposalstatus) is useful too

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski by using && that would mean both conditions need to be true for the query to execute right? so would i use | | for OR? because i need either of those status codes to be present for the code to execute

Comment: @user610 If you use `||` with `!=` either of them negates the other. If the value is `!= 1`, it may be `== 5`, but the logical OR would still cause that condition to be true. So you need it to be != 1 AND != 5.  You could also express it with arrays:  `if (!in_array($proposalstatus, array(1,5)))`

Comment: oh i see! ill try that now! thanks Michael :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions aren't mutually exclusive

```
if ($count < 1) { 
  some stuff
}

if ($count == 1) {
 ...
} else 
 ... this code will execute when $count is *NOT* equal to 1,
  which includes when it's LESS than 1, e.g. "< 1" is true here
}
```

Perhaps you want

```
if ($count == 1) {
} else if ($count < 1) {
} else {
}
```

So that the final else will only run if/when `$count >= 1`

Comment: thanks for your response. Yeah basically, i just want to check if the count is 1 and if it is then to return the first message and if its not then to execute the second part. so you're saying i should do this as an  else if condition?

Comment: well, consider that your code has part 1 (the first if), and then parts 2A and 2B. as written, you'd execute parts 1 and 2B if `$count` really is 1. no idea if that's what you want.

Comment: im a little confused. part 1 would check whether or not the count == 1 and if it doesn't then part 2A would be count < 1 which would then check the status of the proposal and if thats all good then i just want it to continue from there. i think I'm confused myself because i have lots of nested if statements to check various things

Comment: is it possible to have an if else within another if else? without it causing issues?

Comment: you can nest if() as deeply as you want, but it's usually a sign of bad code design, and makes it very hard to follow the program logic. it's an opinion, but anything deeper than 2 levels should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

replace your condition with proposal status 1 or 5

```
if(!($proposalstatus == 1 || $proposalstatus == 5)) {
$feedback = '<p class="text-danger">The proposal is not at a status where it can be accepted</p>';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. both this solution and the one provided by @MichaelBerkowski work perfectly :-)